# Stuck in solving the Hermite DE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, power-series

As a part of solving the Schrödinger equation<sup>1</sup> for quantum Harmonic oscillator:

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
 \left(-\frac{d^2}{d\tilde{x}^2} + \tilde{x}^2\right) \tilde{\psi}(\tilde{x}) = \tilde{E} \tilde{\psi}(\tilde{x}) \iff \frac{d^2 \tilde{\psi}(\tilde{x}) }{d\tilde{x}^2} = (\tilde{x}^2 - \tilde{E}) \tilde{\psi}(\tilde{x}) 
\end{equation}

I'm looking for a solution of the form:

\begin{equation}
 \tilde{\psi}(\tilde{x}) = \tilde{x}^{k} e^{-\frac{\tilde{x}^2}{2}} = h(\tilde{x})e^{-\frac{\tilde{x}^2}{2}}
\end{equation}

which, when substituted in (1) leads to the Hermite differential equation:

\begin{equation}
 \frac{d^{2}h}{d\tilde{x}^2} - 2\tilde{x}\frac{dh}{d\tilde{x}} + (\tilde{E} - 1)h = 0
\end{equation}

I'm trying to construct a power series solution $h = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} a_{k} \tilde{x}^{k}$. Substituting back in the equation:

\begin{equation}
 \sum_{k = 2}^{\infty} k (k - 1) a_{k} \tilde{x}^{k-2} - 2\tilde{x}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} k a_{k} \tilde{x}^{k-1} +  (\tilde{E} - 1)\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} a_{k} \tilde{x}^{k} = 0
\end{equation}

After a shift on the first sum and peeling of the initial term of the first and the last sum:

\begin{equation}
 2a_{0} + \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} (k + 2)(k + 1) a_{k+2} \tilde{x}^{k} - 2\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} k a_{k} \tilde{x}^{k} + a_{0}(\tilde{E} - 1) + (\tilde{E} - 1)\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_{k} \tilde{x}^{k} = 0
\end{equation}

Powers and indexes match, so:

\begin{equation}
 2a_{0} + a_{0}(\tilde{E} - 1) + \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}[(k + 2)(k + 1) a_{k+2} - (2k - \tilde{E} + 1) a_{k} ]\tilde{x}^{k} = 0
\end{equation}

Finally, all the coefficients must be equal to zero, so:

\begin{equation}
a_{k+2} = \frac{(2k - \tilde{E} + 1)}{(k + 2)(k + 1)} a_{k}
\end{equation}

### First (smaller) problem.

From the above, $\tilde{E} = 2k + 1$. But from the peeled of terms $a_{0}(\tilde{E} + 1) = 0$. What should I do with the second relation?

### Second (main) problem.

I expect that by solving the recurrence relation I should somehow deduce that the solution, $h(\tilde{x})$, are the Hermite polynomials, however, I have no idea how to do that. Could you please suggest how to do that?

---

<sub>1.The unit-free time-independent 1D.</sub>

Comment: There is a typo in Equation (1). Also, why the tildes?

Comment: @minimax Thanks. The tildes remained after nondimensionalization, through the following substitution $x = x_c \tilde{x}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I can only answer your first minor question for sure. Nevertheless I can provide  argumentation for your major problem but it does not involve an explicit solution for the recurrence relation.

---

You are right about arguing to peal out the initial terms of the first and the third but you made a slight mistake concerning the first sum. Hence your sums look like

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)(k+2)a_{k+2}\tilde{x}^k-2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}ka_k\tilde{x}^k+(\tilde{E}-1)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k\tilde{x}^k=0$$

the initial term of the first sum is given by $2a_{\color{red}{2}}$ since we are dealing with the subscript $a_{k+2}$ instead of $a_k$ in connection with the first sum. So your condition would be

$$a_2=\frac{(1-\tilde{E})}{2}a_0$$

which is simply the same as you would get by writing down recurrence relation in general.

---

I was only able to deduce the recurrence relation back to two different terms concerning odd and even indices. For them I got

$$\begin{align}
a_{2k}&=\frac{(4k-3-\tilde{E})(4k-7-\tilde{E})\cdots(1-\tilde{E})}{(2k)!}a_0\\
a_{2k+1}&=\frac{(4k-1-\tilde{E})(4k-5-\tilde{E})\cdots(3-\tilde{E})}{(2k+1)!}a_1
\end{align}$$

but similiar to you I have no idea how to show that this relaions equal the Hermite Polynomials. However I guess you can dodge solving these relations by just looking at the DE which define the Hermite Polynomials. The general (physicists') [Hermite DE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite's_differential_equation) is given by

$$u''-2xu'+2nu=0$$

and the solutions are the Hermite Polynomials of the kind $H_n(x)$. Setting $n=\frac{(\tilde{E}-1)}2$ (and $u=h(\tilde{x})$) leads to your DE

$$h''(\tilde{x})-2\tilde{x}h'(\tilde{x})+(\tilde{E}-1)h(\tilde{x})=0$$

and therefore the solutions of this equation are Hermite Polynomials of $\frac{(\tilde{E}-1)}2$th-order. [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=e602dcdecb1843943960b5197efd3f2a) agrees on this by providing the solution

$$h(x)=c_1 H_{\frac{\tilde{E}-1}2}(x)+c_2~_1F_1\left(\frac{1-\tilde{E}}4;\frac12;x^2\right)$$

where $_1F_1$ is the confluent hypergeometric function and the [defined function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Relation_to_confluent_hypergeometric_functions) is closely related to the Hermite Polynomials.

---

While working on the solution defined by $_1F_1$ I figured out a way how to deduce this function back to the recurrence relation given for $2k$. Consider the [Confluent Hypergeometric Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Kummer's_equation) $_1F_1(a;b;x)$ defined as power series

$$_1F_1(a;b;x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a)_k}{(b)_k}\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

where $(a)_k, (b)_k$ denotes the [Pochhammer Symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials). Plugging in $a=\frac{1-\tilde{E}}{4}, b=\frac12$ and $x=x^2$ yields to

$$\begin{align}
_1F_1\left(\frac{1-\tilde{E}}{4};\frac12;x^2\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\frac{1-\tilde{E}}4\right)_k}{\left(\frac12\right)_k}\frac{x^{2k}}{k!}
\end{align}$$

The occuring fraction can be simplified by using the definition of the Pochhammer Symbol and the [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial#Relation_to_the_factorial)

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\left(\frac{1-\tilde{E}}4\right)_k}{\left(\frac12\right)_k k!}=\frac{\frac{(1-\tilde{E})\cdots(4k-7-\tilde{E})(4k-3-\tilde{E})}{4^k}}{\frac{(2k-1)!!}{2^k}k!}&=\frac{(1-\tilde{E})\cdots(4k-7-\tilde{E})(4k-3-\tilde{E})}{2^k~k!~(2k-1)!!}\\
&=\frac{(1-\tilde{E})\cdots(4k-7-\tilde{E})(4k-3-\tilde{E})}{(2k)!}=a_{2k}
\end{align}$$

Hence this way can be gone backwards aswell I guess this is a possibility to show the connection of the power series solution of the DE to the Hermite Polynomials. Howsoever I am still not sure about the odd coefficients.